# PHP Creating entries in different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a project and stuck with something.

I am looking for a way to join two different tables. When you create an entry in one table, it will automatically create an entry in another table.

For example lets say I am creating  new patients for a system. When I input all data in to the form and click submit, all of the data is then stored in the patients table under the unique patient id. 
Now where I have created a row for Bob in the patients table, I would like for it to also create a row for Bob in the accounting table. So that the accounting data would be tied with the patient data. 
So when I submit for a new patient, I would it to also create a new row in the accounting table that can refer to the patient it's created for.

I am not sure if I made my question clear..

EDIT:
Thanks for all the help! I managed to get it up and working with the following..

```
<?
session_start();    

include "database_connect.inc";

$sql="INSERT into patients SET patient_fname='".addslashes($_POST['fname'])."',
                               patient_initial='".$_POST['initial']."', 
                               patient_lname='".addslashes($_POST['lname'])."', 
                               address='".addslashes($_POST['address'])."',
                               city='".addslashes($_POST['city'])."',
                               state='".$_POST['state']."',
                               zipcode='".$_POST['zip']."',
                               phone1label='".$_POST['phone1label']."',
                               phone1='".$_POST['phone1']."',
                               phone2label='".$_POST['phone2label']."',
                               phone2='".$_POST['phone2']."',
                               phone3label='".$_POST['phone3label']."',
                               phone3='".$_POST['phone3']."',
                               phone4label='".$_POST['phone4label']."',
                               phone4='".$_POST['phone4']."',
                               dateofinjury='".$_POST['dateofinjury']."',
                               office_location='".$_POST['officelocation']."',
                               law_office1='".$_POST['lawoffice1']."',
                               law_office2='".$_POST['lawoffice2']."',
                               insurance1='".$_POST['insurance1']."',
                               pip='".$_POST['pip']."',
                               claim1='".$_POST['claim1']."',
                               insurance3='".$_POST['insurance3']."',
                               claim3='".$_POST['claim3']."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$cn);
if (!$result) die("ERROR - Query failed while trying to add a new patient record!<br>".$sql);

$sql="INSERT INTO accounts (patient_id,patient_name,patient_lname) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'".$_POST['fname']."','".$_POST['lname']."')";


if (!mysql_query($sql,$cn))
    {
    die('Error' . mysql_error());   
    }

header("location:createpatient.php");
```

?>

Comment: I knew there was a reason people hired programmers

Comment: how far you go with the script?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Code is supposed included with questions so others can find issues with your current effort, and then help out. [The Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) is great spot to see what questions are accepted and what are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Jean Gkol, I haven't started on the script mainly because I don't know where to begin..

Comment: all right then. :p wait ... :D

Comment: edit your question and provide your other (before and after) script in a page where the 'question' should be answered

Comment: besides, we do not know what type of script you use (mysql, mysqli or PDO). Why? because you didn;t give us a little small script on your question in order to get the best answer,right? are you with me?

Comment: I understand. I'm currently trying to work a script out on my own. Using mysql

Comment: good. now give me your "before and after" script of your question, okay? it's okay you're using mysql. don't worry for voting down. it's just a game. and I'm sure you're going to move to mysqli or PDO then, right? :D

Comment: now @Elijah, please see my answer and tell me if it works or not. That's what I can share based on your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, I prefer suggest you this concept:

example:

```
table1 name: patients
table2 name: accounting

indicator:
patient_id in patients table1
accounting_id in accounting table2
```

then, let's do it!:

```
<?php    
$sql="INSERT INTO patients (patient_fname, ...) 
VALUES ('$_POST[patient_fname]','....')";
mysql_query($sql);
if (!mysql_query($sql,$cn))
    {
    die('Error' . mysql_error());   
    }

$getIdInTable1 = mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS patient_id 
FROM patients");
$setID = mysql_fetch_assoc($getIdInTable1);

$sql="INSERT INTO accounting (patient_id, ....) 
VALUES ({$setID['accounting_id']}, '$_POST['patient_id']','....')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$cn))
    {
    die('Error' . mysql_error());   
    }

mysql_close($db_server);
header("location:createpatient.php");
exit();
?>
```

'Hope this really help you.

Comment: Thank you, that helped out a little. I do however still have a question. When I'm inserting patients, I have the id as auto_increment so I'm not actually imputing a value. When I run that script, my patient_id in accounts is always left out blank

Comment: since the ID is auto_incr, just remove the id inside the bracket.

Comment: Thank you for for taking your time and answering my question. However I still come across the problem where patient_id in account is always 0. I didn't fully understand that. I'll edit in my current script into my question.

Answer (score 0):

At first give it a try, then ask where you get actually stuck.

If i were you, i would try something like this.

```
  BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO patients(name,details)
      VALUES('test', 'test');
    INSERT INTO patient_profiles (patient_id, information) 
      VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'something useful');
    COMMIT;
```

Please refer some [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/).

Answer (score 0):

it s better than You use a manual progressive max code to join tables instead of id